# Silverlight - how to draw a line with an arc?

Tags: silverlight, geometry, lines

I am developing a small silverlight application (using siverlight 4 and c#). In my application I need to draw coordinates based on their X,Y. Then, I need to draw lines between some of the points, based on the connections between them. Since there can be several lines, and I cannot have them all intersecting each other (as it will turn this into a mess), I need to draw some of my lines with an arch.

So, What would be the best way to approach this issue?

- Create my own x,y system - position elements in points and draw lines - If so How can I draw a line with an arch?
- Use a ready control that provides similar capabilities? If so, what control?

Thank You!

Attached is a small image to illustrate my need (I am no big painter, sorry).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at drawing Bezier curves ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) and learn about the different geometry types ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189068%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

Below is a code sample to get you started that will produce the following image:
[image: Bezier Curve Sample]

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="50,50">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                       <BezierSegment 
                                           Point1="50,20"
                                           Point2="120,170"
                                           Point3="350,150"
                                       /> 
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Gold" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Gold" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="350,150" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: is there any way to do it with the simple "Line" class?

Comment: A line can only be a straight line. You don't have many options here. Bezier curves are definitely your best and, very likely, only choice.

Comment: I see, do you know of any open source framework that easily supports positioning points and drawing between them?

Comment: I don't but you shouldn't feel discouraged from learning about Bezier curves. If you spend a bit of time reading on MSDN and then studying my answer and you'll be able to handle it on your own.

Comment: Great, thank you. Do Bezier curves support animation? Can I animate the line's drawing?

Comment: It depends. You can animate the "angles" (ie: control points) of the curve but I'm not sure if you can animate the actual drawing of the curve. It is an interesting question and might be worth opening a new question to see what people come up with.

Comment: ok, great. you can see the follow-up question in this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547982/silverlight-animate-bezier-curves-line-drawing

Comment: @Alison, is there any way to draw a dotted BezierSegment ?